# Hide header in bottom tab navigator

Tags: react-native

When I am trying to adding bottom tab navigation then I just got stack tab upper the search components, can you help me to hide or erase it?

Here's my code, and it shows up like this.

```
    const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
    
    const Settings = () => (
      <SafeArea>
        <Text>Settings</Text>
      </SafeArea>
    );
    const Maps = () => (
      <SafeArea>
        <Text>Maps G</Text>
      </SafeArea>
    );
    
    import {
      useFonts as useOswald,
      Oswald_400Regular,
    } from "@expo-google-fonts/oswald";
    import { useFonts as useLato, Lato_400Regular } from "@expo-google-fonts/lato";
    
    export default function App() {
      const [oswaldLoaded] = useOswald({
        Oswald_400Regular,
      });
    
      const [latoLoaded] = useLato({
        Lato_400Regular,
      });
    
      if (!oswaldLoaded || !latoLoaded) {
        return null;
      }
    
      return (
        <>
          <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <NavigationContainer>
              <Tab.Navigator>
                <Tab.Screen name="Restaurant" component={RestaurantScreen} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Maps" component={Maps} />
                <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
              </Tab.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
          </ThemeProvider>
          <ExpoStatusBar style={"auto"} />
        </>
      );
    }
```

Here is my image for the bottom tab navigation ->
[show up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sID3T.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You are having a header in the screen as part of BottomTabNavigation.
adding screenOption Like below will solve this

```
      <Tab.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} >
        <Tab.Screen name="Restaurant" component={RestaurantScreen} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Maps" component={Maps} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Settings" component={Settings} />
      </Tab.Navigator>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the header with `headerShown: false` for a single route

```
<Stack.Navigator
  initialRouteName="Settings"
  screenOptions={{
    headerShown: false, // hide header 
 }}>
```

Take a look at my [sample](https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/bottom-navigation-example)

Or for the tab navigator with:

```
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Feed"
    tabBarOptions={{
      headerShown: false,    
    }}>
```